# How I can notify wpf owned window of closing?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

If i set a owned window like that :

```
OwnedWindow ownedWindow = new OwnedWindow();
ownedWindow.Owner = this;
ownedWindow.Show();
```

it' possible to get notificated about the ownedWindow closing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.

```
OwnedWindow ownedWindow = new OwnedWindow();
ownedWindow.Owner = this;
ownedWindow.Closing += new System.ComponentModel.CancelEventHandler(ownedWindow_Closing);
ownedWindow.Show();
```

This handler should be in owner window.

```
void ownedWindow_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
{

}
```

Comment: Thanks, it's that i was searching!

Comment: Resharper tipped me, that you can simplify this: ownedWindow.Closing= ownedWindow_Closing  is also accepted